# Operator overloading + in order to sum two object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am new in c++ and I want to sum two object thanks to operator overloading but the problem is that my program crash during the running of the program, and I don't know where can be the problem that I have to fix in order to compile my code well.

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Personnage.h"

int main()
{
    Personnage rony(32), marc(20);
    Personnage resultat;

    resultat = rony + marc;


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Personnage.h

```
class Personnage
{
public:
    Personnage();
    Personnage(int force);
private:
    int power;
};
Personnage operator+(Personnage const& first, Personnage const& second);
```

Personnage.cpp

```
#include "Personnage.h"
#include <string>

Personnage::Personnage() : power(0)
{

}
Personnage::Personnage(int force) : power(force)
{

}
Personnage operator+(Personnage const& first, Personnage const& second)
{
    Personnage resultat;
    resultat = first + second;

    return resultat;

}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have you debugged it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your operator is endlessly calling itself. This statement:

```
resultat = first + second;
```

...invokes your operator, which then executes that statement again, etc., etc. Eventually you get a stack overflow.

Your `operator+` needs to decide what it semantically means to add two `Personnage` together. For example

```
Personnage operator+(Personnage const& first, Personnage const& second)
{
    int total_power = first.power + second.power;
    return Personnage(total_power);
}
```

To access the private members, typically you can declare the overloaded operators as `friend` in your class

```
class Personnage
{
public:
    Personnage();
    Personnage(int force);

    friend Personnage operator+(Personnage const& first, Personnage const& second);

private:
    int power;
};
```

Comment: This is not work because variable power is private and operator is outside the class

Comment: Then put the operator inside the class

Comment: Since my answer was virtually the same as yours (but not updated to handle the friend issue), I've just taken the bit that was different and added it above.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
friend Personnage operator+(Personnage const& first, Personnage const& second)
{
    Personnage resultat;
    resultat.power = first.power + second.power;

    return resultat;

}
```

or

```
friend Personnage operator+(Personnage const& first, Personnage const& second)
{
    Personnage resultat(first.power + second.power);
    return resultat;
}
```

or

```
friend Personnage operator+(Personnage const& first, Personnage const& second)
{
    return (Personnage resultat(first.power + second.power));
}
```

Also declare as `friend` in .h file.

All are same, just different calls to different types of constructor.